# Material2 How to replace md-radio-button default icon with material icons

Tags: css, angular-material2, google-material-icons

```
<md-radio-group name="more_options" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
    <md-radio-button name="more_options" [value]="Summer" class="margin-r">Summer</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button name="more_options" [value]="Autumn" class="margin-r">Autumn</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

For material icons, there isn't any CSS attribute such as "content" which can be replaced with appropriate icon code to replace md-radio-button icon with some other material icon. 
Is there any way to replace default radio buttons with material icons through pure CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Another material component, `md-icon`, uses the Material icon font or you can define your own font class or use SVG. https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview

Comment: I want to use <md-radio-button> component, but want to hook material icon in place of radio button..  So material icons with md-radio behavior. I can create a custom directive, but wanna check if there is any way to achieve this by pure CSS.

Comment: Have you checked out button toggle? "<md-button-toggle> are on/off toggles with the appearance of a button. These toggles can be configured to behave as either radio-buttons or checkboxes. While they can be standalone, they are typically part of a md-button-toggle-group."  https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview